# Enabling SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA through Python Boto3 for a cognito user

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito, chalice

I need to enable MFA for Cognito users as per their requirements. I tried SMS MFA & it worked perfectly, but when it comes to Software MFA **(SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA)** i couldn't find any proper documents or examples on how to enable it through code. Either through Javascript or through python **(Boto3)**
[image]

The above-mentioned picture represents my MFA settings for the Cognito user pool. i tried some examples for javascript, but some functions threw errors

```
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function(result) {
        var accessToken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
    },

    onFailure: function(err) {
        alert(err.message || JSON.stringify(err));
    },

    mfaSetup: function(challengeName, challengeParameters) {
        cognitoUser.associateSoftwareToken(this);
    },

    associateSecretCode: function(secretCode) {
        var challengeAnswer = prompt('Please input the TOTP code.', '');
        cognitoUser.verifySoftwareToken(challengeAnswer, 'My TOTP device', this);
    },

    selectMFAType: function(challengeName, challengeParameters) {
        var mfaType = prompt('Please select the MFA method.', ''); // valid values for mfaType is "SMS_MFA", "SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA"
        cognitoUser.sendMFASelectionAnswer(mfaType, this);
    },

    totpRequired: function(secretCode) {
        var challengeAnswer = prompt('Please input the TOTP code.', '');
        cognitoUser.sendMFACode(challengeAnswer, this, 'SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA');
    },

    mfaRequired: function(codeDeliveryDetails) {
        var verificationCode = prompt('Please input verification code', '');
        cognitoUser.sendMFACode(verificationCode, this);
    },
});
```

`cognitoUser.sendMFASelectionAnswer(mfaType, this);`
throws an error

```
        var challengeAnswer = prompt('Please input the TOTP code.', '');
        cognitoUser.verifySoftwareToken(challengeAnswer, 'My TOTP device', this);
    }
```

throws an error

I even tried the same to enable it from the python

```
response = client.set_user_mfa_preference(
                SMSMfaSettings={
                    'Enabled': True|False,
                    'PreferredMfa': True|False
                },
                SoftwareTokenMfaSettings={
                    'Enabled': True|False,
                    'PreferredMfa': True|False
                },
                AccessToken=token_
            )
```

But it says invalid access token,
token_ = 'eqQwo59dnjwj*******'

Answer (score 3):

After a detailed study on cognito with boto3 (**Python**), i found a solution to enable Software MFA

1. Associate software token to the user

```
response = client.associate_software_token(
         AccessToken=user_as_json['access_token'],
    )
```

Which return a secret code. use otpauth to make the secret code into a qrcode

2. Verify the token received from the use

```
response = client.verify_software_token(
            AccessToken=user_as_json['access_token'],
            UserCode='Code received from the user',
            FriendlyDeviceName='ABC'
        )
```

3. Set user MFA Preference

```
response_1 = client.set_user_mfa_preference(
            SMSMfaSettings={
                'Enabled': False,
                'PreferredMfa': False
            },
            SoftwareTokenMfaSettings={
                'Enabled': True,
                'PreferredMfa': True
            },
            AccessToken='Access Token'
        )
```

**Note:** Preferred MFA can be set only if either of the MFA is enabled.

**Note:** Both the MFA can be Enabled, But only one can be set to preferred at
a time